# Retrofit выбивает ошибку

Tags: android, retrofit

Api: https://api.myjson.com/bins/upt7z

Api:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("upt7z")
    Call<List<Photo>> listData();
}
```

Photo:

```
public class Photo {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private Double latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private Double longitude;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;


    public Photo(Integer id, String title, String description, Double latitude, Double longitude, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

Call<List<Photo>>  photo_api = api.listData();

photo_api.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i("if","response " + response.body().size());
        } else {
            Log.i("else","response code " + response.code());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i("onFailure",t.toString());
    }
});
```

Ошибка:

```
I/onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, ваш вызов сейчас идёт на адрес https://api.myjson.com/upt7z. Вам нужно добавить path `bins` либо в base url либо в @GET path.

Во-вторых, вы ожидаете в ответ массив объектов `Photo`. А запрос на https://api.myjson.com/bins/upt7z возвращается json объект, который внутри себя содержит массив Photo. Создайте новый класс обёртку и установите его в качестве респонса. Например:

```
public class PhotoResponse {
    public List<Photo> photos;
}

public interface Api {
    @GET("bins/upt7z")
    Call<PhotoResponse> listData();
}
```